# What Unicode fonts does Ubuntu console use?

Tags: command-line, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

As per subject I would like to know what are the fonts that Ubuntu console uses, especially the eastern Unicode.

I tried loading the *Ubuntu Monospace* both regular and bold, but seems like all the eastern utf8 glyphs are missing.

How does the Ubuntu terminal display such glyphs?

What fonts does it use?

Comment: my guess would be that it uses the Noto family - Noto Mono or Noto Sans Mono

Comment: But what about the unicode asian characters?

Comment: Noto is usually the font used for CJK characters on Linux...

Comment: @ashvatthama Tried to load /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoMono-Regular.ttf but looks like the CJK glyphs are missing from this ttf file...

Comment: @Emanuele Are you referring to a GUI terminal application (gnome-terminal, konsole, etc) or the text-mode terminal (`tty`)?

Comment: @xiota I'm referring to the GUI terminal. Another challenge I would add is the _monospace_ requirement for the given CJK font, which I don't think Ubuntu (or other OS) have...

Comment: @Emanuele What OS are you using? Which terminal program are you using? Have you looked in preferences to see what font is selected?

Comment: @xiota using Ubuntu 18.04 - default terminal; it's ubuntu for western chars, what about CJK? Again, this is the point of this question...

Comment: @Emanuele It's probably using a fallback font. I don't know how to find the fallback font used for specific glyphs. It's probably easier to search for "CJK" in `synaptic` to find the packages that are installed. On my computer, the Noto CJK fonts are located at `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto` (different directory than the one you previously checked).